# Spill unique list of years from a set of row data in to a single column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data running in row format in ascending date order :

[image]

I'd like to create a function that will spill the unique years from a single cell down a column. Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(1:1,TRUE))`

Comment: `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(1:1,1))`

Answer (score 3):

Combine `UNIQUE` with `TOCOl`:

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:J1))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: used `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(Q2#))` with the data being flexible. Worked great.